# Generating new form with its specific classes in QT MSVC2012

Tags: c++, qt, qt-msvc-addin

I know my question is a bit more general than ones of you might think, but I still need the help I couldn't find on Google.

I am working with more Qt projects in Visual Studio 2012.

I have a Qt library project in my solution (a `.dll`) and I create a new item like below:

[image]

he files tree changes look like below:

```
 + Form Files
 |---- preferencesWindow.ui
 + Generated Files
 |---- ui_preferencesWindow.h
```

How can I get the other classes I need autmatically? It looks very complex to write them by myself so...

**A bit of explanation**

Inside Qt Creator, we have some options when we want to "Add new...". The window looks like this:

[image]

1. If we choose for `Qt Designer Form Class`, then it is going to generate the `.ui` file, the `ui_window.h` and also `dialog.cpp` and `dialog.h` (the class that has to manage slots and other things. it is the class for implementation purposes of that dialog)
2. If we choose for `Qt Designed Form`, then it is going to generate the `.ui` file and `ui_[name].h`, without the class responsible for slots and other things.

Visual Studio Add-In only provides the second option, under another name. I am trying to get the behavior of `Qt Designer Form Class`.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the other classes ... automatically"?

Comment: See my edit, if you need more explanation, I will provide it

Comment: As you can see, a things I forgot to write, by "get the other classes" I mean the "matching classes for implementation purposes". (You can read that in the second screen-shot I put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MSVC, right-click on your project, select Add and then Class. In the templates dialog that pops up, select Qt5 Classes, and then Qt5GuiClass.

Fill in the fields and the three sets of files will be created for you.

Comment: this looks promising, I will try it tomorrow when I am in front of my pc